# How do I save a new object using NHibernate when it already has an ID?

Tags: nhibernate, persistence

I'm using GUIDs for the identifier on my objects it is assigned when the entity is instantiated. I want to save them using NHibernate and have NHibernate determine whether it's a new object or not. If it's a new object, it should INSERT it, otherwise it should UPDATE it.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding either [version](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-version) or [timestamp](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp) to your entity.

Without one of those [it's impossible for Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-assigned) to figure out whether your entity should be inserted or updated since you're using an assigned identifier.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it, though I would've thought that the `SaveOrUpdate()` method would hit up the database to see if the ID exists, and save or update it accordingly.

Comment: It won't, but there's nothing preventing you from doing that yourself - you can easily write a method in your DAO that would call `Get()` first and subsequently save or merge your object based on its result.